# Adding a separator (divider) to a react-select Select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am using the react-select API. It is straightforward to create a Select:

```
import Select from "react-select";

<Select
    options={someOptions}
    value={someOption}
    ...
/>
```

What I am trying to do is to create a separator (divider) between the first option in the selection, and the rest options. Is there a way as a part of the API to do this?

Comment: couldn't you add a style attribute to it?

Comment: <Select options={someOptions} value={someOption} style={selectStyle}/>

Comment: This is what I came into my mind but I was not 100% sure if it is the best way to do it. I may fallback to it if I do not have alternatives.

Comment: https://react-select.com/home if  you go here that is how they add their own styles to the component